# Express static serving only a single file correctly

Tags: node.js, express, static

It works fine on my dev env but on my live it makes nonsense errors.

The output is

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/sai/apps/site/site/img/image1.png'
```

The problem is this part of the path specifically: `/sai/apps/site/site/...`
It should be `/sai/apps/site/public/...`, just like in my dev env.

Why is this happening?

Bonus issue: Out of all 10 images that I serve on the site, only 1 is loaded correctly, and it resides in the exact same folder as the other images.

This is so weird and I can't understand what's going on.

EDIT:

I am using `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Comment: Show the whole Express initialization code

Comment: `app.use(express.static('public'))` looks like Express should get you files from `public` folder from the root of your app as `/some_file_from_public_folder.png`

Comment: @Anatoly it's literally any express tutorial code found online. My code works 100% on my dev env and a different test server, but on my live server it's decided to not work for some reason.

Comment: did you publish your app not into a root domain path?

Comment: @Anatoly yes. It's published under a subdomain like `https://xxxx.mysite.com/`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: No, I mean under root subfolder/route. Like in `https://xxxx.mysite.com/app`

Comment: Maybe you have some conditional code that depends on process.NODE.env?

Comment: Aah I see. No I just cloned my repo as is, and it works as expected on dev env.

Comment: What was the request for '/sai/apps/site/site/img/image1.png' ?

Comment: It was a simple GET from my HTML code `<img src="/img/image1.png">`.
I am scratching a hole in my skull because I just can't figure out why this would happen.

Comment: Can you look at the whole request in browser dev tools?

Comment: It says the following on the request: `Request URL: https://xxxxx.mysite.com/img/image1.png`.